# how scala infer method's parameterss

Tags: scala

I notice by chance that scala can infer the type of some method's parameter.
But I don't understand the exact rule. Can someone explain me why the test1 method work and why the test2 method does not work

```
object Test {
  def test1[A]: A => A = a => a
  def test2[A]: A = a
}
```

I can't find a good title for my question since I don't understand what is happening in  this two lines.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Neither of the two methods have any parameters. Nothing is being inferred here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def test1[A]: A => A         =    a => a
              |____|              |____|

         the return type       an anonymous function
     (a function from A to A)  (`a` is a parameter of this function)


def test2[A]: A =                 a
              |                   |
        the return type      an unbound value
             (A)         (i.e. not in scope, a is not declared)
```

The gotcha is that in the first example `a` is the parameter of an anonymous function, whereas in the second example `a` is never declared.

Answer (score 2):

`test1` is a method that takes no input and returns a function `A => A`.  The name `a` is given as the imput parameter of the funtion and the function simple reutrns `a`, it's input.

`test2` is a method that takes no input returns a value of type `A`.  The method is defined to return the variable named `a` but that variable has never been declared so you get an error.  you could redefine the method to be `def test2[A](a: A): A = a` and it would work, because now `a` has been declared as a variable of type `A`, it is the parameter of the method.